# foreign key not inserting in child table using propel synfony 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, propel

schema.xml

```
         //This is my schema.

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <database name="default" namespace="UserBundle\Model" defaultIdMethod="native">
          <table name="userEmail" phpName="userEmail" idMethod="native">
            <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
            <column name="user_id" phpName="UserId" type="INTEGER" required="false"/>
            <column name="email_id" phpName="EmailId" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
            <foreign-key foreignTable="users" name="user_email_ibfk_1" onDelete="RESTRICT" onUpdate="RESTRICT"><reference local="user_id" foreign="id"/></foreign-key>
            <index name="userDetails_FI_1">
              <index-column name="user_id"/>
            </index>
            <vendor type="mysql">
              <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
            </vendor>
          </table>


        <table name="userMobile" phpName="userMobile" idMethod="native">
            <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
            <column name="user_id" phpName="UserId"  type="INTEGER" required="false"/>
            <column name="mobile_no" phpName="MobileNo" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
            <foreign-key foreignTable="users" name="user_mobile_ibfk_1" onDelete="RESTRICT" onUpdate="RESTRICT"><reference local="user_id" foreign="id"/></foreign-key>
            <index name="userDetails_FI_1">
              <index-column name="user_id"/>
            </index>
            <vendor type="mysql">
              <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
            </vendor>
          </table>



          <table name="users" phpName="Users" idMethod="native">
            <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
            <column name="first_name" phpName="FirstName" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
            <column name="last_name" phpName="LastName" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
            <column name="school_name" phpName="SchoolName" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
            <column name="college_name" phpName="CollegeName" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
            <column name="blood_group" phpName="BloodGroup" type="VARCHAR" size="10" required="true"/>
            <column name="gender" phpName="Gender" type="VARCHAR" size="15" required="true"/>
            <column name="date_of_birth" phpName="DateOfBirth" type="DATE" required="true"/>
            <vendor type="mysql">
              <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
            </vendor>
          </table>
        </database>
```

UserType.php

```
        //This is my Form Builder page.

        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
            {
                $builder->add('firstName');
                $builder->add('lastName');
                $builder->add('schoolName');
                $builder->add('collegeName');
                $builder->add('bloodGroup');
                $builder->add('gender', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                  'male' => 'Male',
                  'female' => 'Female'
                ),
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'data'     => 'male'
            ));
                $builder->add('dateOfBirth', 'date', array(
            'years' => range(date('Y') - 80, date('Y') - 0)
           ));

                $builder->add('userEmails', 'collection', array('type' => new userEmailType(),
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'data_class' => NULL,
                    'allow_add' =>true,
                    'allow_delete'=>true));
                $builder->add('userMobiles', 'collection', array('type' => new userMobileType(),
                'allow_add' =>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true));

            }
```

new.html.twig

```
    //This is my twig page

    <form action="" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
              {{ form_widget(form) }}
              <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

UserController.php

```
This is my controller page.


public function newAction() {

        $users = new Users();
        $userEmail = new userEmail();
        $userMobile = new userMobile();

        $form = $this->createForm(new UsersType(), $users);

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {


            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $users->save();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_listpage',array('pageId' =>1)));

            }
        }

        return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

I am using above codes to insert user details,users email and mobile number with user_id as foreign key using propel and symfony2.

If I try to insert its only inserting email Id and Mobile number not inserting user_id (Foreign Key) value in child tables.

It is my first task in symfony2 with propel.

Comment: If you are posting codes from different files, make sure that you post it separately, not in same code segment

Comment: @ajay I don't no how to do it. Please ask which one you are not understandable.

Comment: why do you have 'data_class' => NULL,  in your form type for emails?

Comment: Why are you copying and pasting? The resources that you find in internet are for references, they won't work by merely copying and pasting the code into your projects... you need to modify them. If you're a beginner, head to coursera.org, learn through free videos...

Comment: @ajay

$builder->add('userEmails', new userEmailType());

I tried to use this method to solve the problem. I got below error message. 

"The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class UserBundle\Model\useremail, but is an instance of class PropelObjectCollection. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class PropelObjectCollection to an instance of UserBundle\Model\useremail. "

so only I added  'data_class' => NULL in that option array.